# Make sure that all constructors call same function c++, design pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Let us assume that we have a class called Node which has a member called sequence and id. We want to print the sequence of the Node in many differnt ways. Instead of adding the print functions directly into the Node class, we put them into a seperate class called NodePrinter. Each Node, needs to have a "working" NodePrinter in any case.

Which implies that:

1. Node has a `NodePrinter * printer` member
2. Every constructor of Node needs to create a `new NodePrinter`

My idea now was to create a `BaseNode` and move the `NodePrinter` into that one. It has only one constructor, which takes a `Node` as an input and assigns it to the `NodePrinter`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class NodePrinter;
class Node;
class BaseNode
{
public:
    BaseNode() = delete;
    BaseNode(Node * node);
    ~BaseNode();

    NodePrinter * printer;
};

class Node: public BaseNode
{
public:
    Node(string sequence): BaseNode(this), sequence(sequence){}
    Node(int id, string sequence): BaseNode(this), sequence(sequence), id(id){}

    int id;
    string sequence;
};

class NodePrinter
{
private:
    Node * node;

public:
    NodePrinter() = delete;
    NodePrinter(Node * node): node(node){}
    void print_node()
    {
        std::cout<<node->sequence<<endl;
    }
};

BaseNode::BaseNode(Node * node)
{
    node->printer = new NodePrinter(node);
}

BaseNode::~BaseNode()
{
    delete printer;
    printer = nullptr;
}



int main()
{
    Node node("abc");
    node.printer->print_node();
    return 0;
}
```

Thereby each node is forced to call `BaseNode(this)` and the resources get allocated.

Is this reasonable, or is this whole approach already twisted from the start? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `NodePrinter * printer;` should probably simply be `NodePrinter printer;` or `std::unique_ptr<NodePrinter> printer;`. move/copy should probably be not defaulted.

Comment: But your hierarchy seems strange. if you change to `void NodePrinter::print_node(const Node&)`, you remove your cyclic dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that seems odd to me is that the printer depends on an instance of `Node`, shouldn't it be possible for a single printer to print multiple nodes? And I also wouldn't have `Node` depend on a `NodePrinter` either, because then you can't print the same node with multiple printers.

Anyhow, if you really need to keep the 1-to-1 correspondence, the simplest way is to just initialize the `NodePrinter` directly where the member variable is declared in `Node`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class Node;

class NodePrinter
{
private:
    Node * node;

public:
    NodePrinter() = delete;
    NodePrinter(Node * node): node(node){}

    void print_node();
};

class Node
{
public:
    Node(std::string sequence) : sequence(std::move(sequence)){}
    Node(int id, std::string sequence) : id(id), sequence(std::move(sequence)) {}

    int id;
    std::string sequence;

    std::unique_ptr<NodePrinter> printer = std::make_unique<NodePrinter>(this);
};

void NodePrinter::print_node()
{
    std::cout<< node->sequence << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    Node node("abc");
    node.printer->print_node();
    return 0;
}
```

Live demo on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/csLtcakDmaKaOkH9).

Comment: Yes I want to keep the 1-to-1 correspondence in my project. Thanks! Did not see the the forest because of all the trees ; )